# how to find javascript link and click on it?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried to use selenium with python to automate some task. The program will navegate the link `javascript:LoadPage('12')` by click on it. However, I couldn't do it with selenium. My codes are below, any suggestion please kindly help.

```
webdriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Security')
webdriver.find_element_by_link_text("javascript:LoadPage('12')")
webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Security')
```

Three of them are the codes that I tried but it doesn't work. I got an error something li`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Security"}`

Thank you in advance.

Edit1: Add html code

```
<table height="40px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="90px" height="40px" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
                <a href="javascript:LoadPage('0')" target="" class="Menu_L1_Link">
                    <p align="center">Status</p>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="90px" height="40px" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
                <a href="javascript:LoadPage('6')" target="" class="Menu_L1_Link">
                    <p align="center">Network</p>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="90px" height="40px" bgcolor="#FFC000">
                <a href="javascript:LoadPage('12')" target="" class="Menu_L1_Active">
                    <p align="center">Security</p>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="90px" height="40px" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
                <a href="javascript:LoadPage('19')" target="" class="Menu_L1_Link">
                    <p align="center">Application</p>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="90px" height="40px" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
                <a href="javascript:LoadPage('26')" target="" class="Menu_L1_Link">
                    <p align="center">Management</p>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try `webdriver.find_element('.Menu_L1_Link')`. Idea is to have a selector. If you need it to be precise, try `.find_element(' a.Menu+L1_Link[href="javascript:LoadPage('12')"] ')`

Comment: @Rajesh it doesn't work beucae in `class="Menu_L1_Link` contained 5 sub menu and getting syntax error for `.find_element(' a.Menu+L1_Link[href="javascript:LoadPage('12')"] ')`

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha can you post your image as html?

Comment: @frianH already addded, thanks

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha Try `webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > a').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
hrefText= "javascript:LoadPage('12')"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='" + hrefText + "']")
```

the find_element_by_xpath can be done as one line, but splitting into two lines makes it simpler with managing `"` and `'` within the strings

This assumes that the webelement is unique based on the html provided.
If there are fruther errors or please share a link to your site and steps on what you're trying to achieve. I'm happy to support.

[Quick update - another method now i can copy the html code]
[update - wrapping it in a webdriverwait]
Using this xpath will allow you to select by text

```
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[p[text()="Security"]]')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[p[text()="Security"]]')))
```

This is the `a` that contains the `p` that has the text `Security` (and is case sensitive).

For `webdriverwait`, You'll need the following imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Highlights as so:
[image: devtools]

---

[update 2 - JS execution]

If you want to inject JS into the browser you can try this:

```
driver.execute_script("javascript:LoadPage('12')")
```

I can't try this as i'm not on your router, but give it a go and let us know.

Comment: it doesn't work, getting error `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[p[text()="Security"]]"}`

Comment: It works against the html you shared (hence the screenshot) :-) - do you need to do any actions to make the menu visible?  - or if you're struggling can you share a link to the site?

Comment: if this is a script based site,are  you aware of how to use webdriverwait?  (again - happy to help with this as you need)

Comment: It is not a pubilc link sir, I'm trying to automate some task with moy router. I just want to click on the element 'Security' which navegate to the javascript link.

Comment: no worries :-)  - so i've updated with a wedriver wait.  Can you try that - and can you confirm if there are any other actions you need to do to get the link to appear on the screen?

Comment: I think some misunderstanding here. I don't want to make "Security" appear on the screen but I want to click on the word "Security" on the screen. Then, it should navegate me to the link `javascript:LoadPage('12')`

Comment: You can't click on the link the make the browser navigate without it being present on screen.  i've added a new bit at the bottom to inject JS into your browser, see if that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219180/discussion-between-sasiwut-chaiyadecha-and-richedwards).

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to click on the element with text as **Security** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td>a[class^='Menu_L1'][href*='12']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td/a[starts-with(@class, 'Menu_L1_')]/p[text()='Security']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)